# using decodable to capture array of nested objects in single line

Tags: ios, json, swift, nested, codable

Below is my json response and the struct which I need to costruct out of it.

condition: I would not like to create any other struct apart from Response,Media and would like to parse in single line as specified below.

```
{
     "name": "xxxx",
     "title": "xxxxxxx",
     "assets": [
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "eeee",
              "desc": "rrrrrr"
            },            {
              "id": "eeee",
            },            {
              "desc": "rrrrrr"
            }]
        }]
}



struct Response {
    let name  : String
    let title : string
    let items : [Media]

    private enum codingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case title = "title"
        case items = "assets.items"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: codingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        title = try container.decode(TrayLayout.self, forKey: .title)
        items = try container.decode([Media].self, forKey: .items)
    }
}
```

Comment: please take a look at following answer and see if that helps to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a new way:

```
struct Media: Codable {
    let id,desc: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id,desc
    }
}
struct Response: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let name,title: String?
    @NestedKey
    let items: [Media]?
    enum CodingKeys: String,NestableCodingKey {
        case name,title,
        case items = "assets/items"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution for your problem.

Considering following is sample json

```
let jsonString = """
{
     "name": "xxxx",
     "title": "xxxxxxx",
     "assets": [
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "id11",
              "desc": "desc11"
            },            {
              "id": "id12",
            },            {
              "desc": "desc13"
            }]
        },{
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "id21",
              "desc": "desc21"
            },            {
              "id": "id22",
            },            {
              "desc": "desc23"
            }]
        }]
}
"""
```

Your structures will look as below

```
struct Media: Codable {
    let id,desc: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id,desc
    }
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let name,title: String?
    let items: [Media]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name,title,items
        case assets = "assets"
    }
    // Decoding
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)

        // Here as the assets contains array of object which has a key as items and then again consist of a array of Media we need to decode as below
        let assets = try container.decode([[String:[Media]]].self, forKey: .assets)

        // At this stage will get assets with a array of array so we first map and retrive the items and then reduce them to one single array
        items = assets.compactMap{$0[CodingKeys.items.rawValue]}.reduce([], +)
    }
}
```

At the end it's time to use it as follows

```
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let myResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

Now you can access the data as below

```
myResponse.name
myResponse.title
myResponse.items
```

Hope this basic code helps you to achieve what you want to do. And then you can go ahead and do more nested parsing(s).

I would like to thanks `Nic Laughter` for [such a detailed article](https://medium.com/@nictheawesome/using-codable-with-nested-json-is-both-easy-and-fun-19375246c9ff); by referring which I managed to come with above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
  let name, title: String
  let assets: [Assets]
}

struct Assets: Decodable {
 let items: [Items]
}

struct Items: Decodable {
  let id, desc: String
}
```

Then you can just decode it like this:

```
guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) else { print("Response not parsed"); return }
```

Comment: Hey rob, i would not like to create new assets struct